# How to use if condition in template function in Typst

Tags: typst

I would like to use an if-condition in a template function to trigger dark mode. The template function has a boolean value `dark` that defaults to `false`. The following code works:

```
set page(fill: rgb("333333")) if dark
set text(fill: rgb("fdfdfd")) if dark
set text(font: "Source Sans Pro") if dark
```

However, when I try to wrap all three lines into an if-condition, I get a blank page (set in dark mode) and then the rest of the document in light mode instead. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  if dark {
    set page(fill: rgb("333333"))
    set text(fill: rgb("fdfdfd"))
    set text(font: "Source Sans Pro")
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` rules only work in their scope and child scopes. The `if` statement creates a new scope, meaning `set` rules are only active at that level:

```js
if dark {
    set page(fill: rgb("333333"))
    // "set" rule is active from here
    ....
} // to here, where the scope ends
```

You can get around this using [`set-if`](https://typst.app/docs/reference/syntax/#code) rules:

```js
set page(fill: rgb("333333")) if dark
set text(fill: rgb("fdfdfd"), font: "Source Sans Pro") if dark
```

But it is inconvenient to do this for multiple rules in a row or when you rely on nested conditions. For more complicated scenarios, I use the following approach:

```js
// Define non-dark mode variables in an outer scope
let (page-fill, text-fill, font) = (none, black, "New Computer Modern")
if dark {
    // Reuse variables from an outer scope, so changes persist
    (page-fill, text-fill, font) = (rgb("333333"), rgb("fdfdfd"), "Source Sans Pro")
}
// Apply set rules in parent scope
set page(fill: page-fill)
set text(fill: text-fill, font: font)
```

Comment: Fascinating, I haven't come across any programming language yet where control flow elements have their own scope.

Comment: This is the case in `c` and its derivatives; `if` blocks with newly defined `int x = <number>` will restore the parent value at the end of the scope.

It is also true for `rust`, on top of which typst was built